# A java jar file runs fine if run from console but generates exception if run at startup

Tags: boot, java, javafx

I wrote a JavaFX program which also utilizes JSON. When  run at startup, the try catch around the JSON parsing piece of the code throws an exception. I can't see the exception printed in the console but I made a graphical alert that pops up when the exception occurs. Any idea why this would happen even thought the program runs normally if run manually? How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the exception? If you can't get the popup to display the exception, how about logging it to a file?

Comment: I used e.toString I received:"Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.

Comment: Are you using relative, or absolute paths?

Comment: Had quite the hassle with this one but ended up using : File file = new File("buttonConfigurationsPI.json") and a scanner + string builder

Comment: My guess is that your application doesn't have permission to put a new file whereever cron is using as its working dir. Try creating a new directory that has 777 permissions, and then use an absolute path to write to that directory. If that works, we'll have a fairly good idea as to what's going on.

Comment: I tried giving 777 to the JSON file, the error persists. Is this what you meant by directory?

Comment: No, a directory is a folder.

Comment: I got confused because  you said write to that directory, but write what?

Comment: Try creating your new file in a directory that has permissions of 777

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53701/discussion-between-jacobm001-and-nawf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was simple as usual. The scripts that were tested in order to run the jar at startup were running it from another directory. I used crontab plus a shell script where I 'cd'ed to the jar directory then ran the jar file. 
Before, I only ran the jar file using its full path, but apparently I have to cd there in order for it to find the JSON files.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.